# How can I automatically open an issue on GitHub when an Android app or another platform like backend or frontend encounters a bug?

Tags: github, issue-tracking

I'm working on an Android application, and I want to automate the process of reporting bugs by automatically opening an issue on GitHub whenever a bug occurs.

Additionally, I would like to extend this functionality to other platforms like backend or frontend development.

What are the recommended approaches or tools to achieve this automation? Are there any existing libraries or services that can help me implement this feature effectively? I would appreciate any guidance or code examples that can help me get started with this automated bug reporting workflow.

For example like this: https://docs.bugsnag.com/product/integrations/issue-tracker/github-issues

Comment: What have you tried? What did you experience that you think there must be something else that is more recommended? And my immediate suggestion is: Use a proxy so that you can keep all reports for the time when Github stops working for your application (e.g. net-split loosing all resources in that part of the internet) so that you can continue on segments of the internet that are not affected by that .

Comment: I only checked one service, but it wasn't free. I'm looking for free services.

Comment: Please add all clarifications to your question by editing it, not by placing it as comment below. Also please provide reference to that service (e.g. its name). Only an idea: Mozilla with the Firefox project was totally fancy with a bug-reporter, maybe they also did it for their Android Firefox and have released the sources?

Comment: Okay, I added one service.